# Update Listview when data is appended to a file?

Tags: c#, listview, file-io

Here's what I am doing:
I am logging messages and date time to a text file which I did successfully. Now I want to add the same to a Listview (or any other control which can be used to achieve this), also as and when the file is updated the Listview should be updated.

I am new to c# so excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FileSystemWatcher

Instantiate an FileSystemWatcher :

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher= new FileSystemWatcher();

watcher.Path = @"c:\folder_that_contains_log_file";
```

Set the notify filter : what events should be observed

```
watcher.NotifyFilter= NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
```

Specify that the FileWatcher can raise events :

```
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Add event handler for the change event for all files from that folder :

```
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Changed);
```

Capture the change event :

```
private void Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

// Get the ful path of the file that changed and rised this change event   

string fileThatChanged = e.FullPath.ToString();

//Check if file that changed is your log file

 if (fileThatChangedPath.equals("path_tot_the_log_file"))           
 {

   // clear items from ListView

   // Read from file line by line

   // Add each line to the ListView

 }

}
```

Comment: Great thanks. I was thinking in the same direction. But is there a way I can bind the Listview control to this file and it will take care of it instead of using filesystemwatcher?

Comment: Ok no problem. Appreciate for the help.

Comment: +1 : Exactly What I was looking for, but I was too lazy to code it myself :-p

Comment: You could directly use `watcher.Filter = "path_tot_the_log_file";` rhater than testing the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you save the changes you made in your code

then you will need to watch when the changes happens to the file

```
FileSystemWatcher watch;
public Load()
        {            
            watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watch.Path = @"C:\tmp";

            watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            // Only watch text files.
            watch.Filter = "*.txt";

            watch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;            
        }

        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            if (e.FullPath == @"C:\tmp\link.txt")
                MessageBox.Show("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);            
        }
```

when changes occurs you will need to get the changes on your own
and add it to the control you want

you can for example get the file content before changing and store it 
then get it after change occurs and compare it

hope i helped

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way I can bind the Listview control to this file and it will take care of it instead of using filesystemwatcher?